# How to add settings for Android web-view that works for both mobile and non mobile friendly URLS?

Tags: android, url, webview, settings

[image]

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.take_webview);
    webView.getSettings()
            .setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebClient());

    Log.d("Feedback url is ", url);
    // enable javascript

    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

I have used above settings and it works fine for non mobile friendly url, but while I used mobile friendly url,web-view behaves as desktop view.
Please help me for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    // display alert message in Web View
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        // Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).setMessage(message).setCancelable(true).show();
        result.confirm();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines of code for these..

```
   WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing() ) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(ContestActivity.this, "Error:" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("YOUR URL HERE");
```

Comment: @PeddiRaju ... It is not opening on the desktop  bro...Is your URLS are right??

Comment: ok....What type of view on mobile, its shows?? Can you plz tell me what exact problem are you facing now...Or you can send the snip shot of mobile with these question...Than i will able to solve yours problem

Comment: Ok..let try me at my end...soon will update you about it...which URL behave as DESKTOP view..?? ...Is it one ssl.capwiz.com/ahca/lrm/feedback.tt?event=45235

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99508/discussion-between-peddiraju-and-ravindra-kushwaha).